# URL validation javascript jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate url and its need to be allow to with and with out http://

that means if user type as http://www.google.com or www.google.com should allow to the user ..

i tried jquery validations class to do this.. no luck

i tried regx as follow its also not working as i want . any help very appreciated

```
<script>

var myVariable = "http://www.google.com/";
if(/^([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test('www.google.com/')) {
  alert("valid url");
} else {
  alert("invalid url");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you call a "valid URL"? Is it a validly formatted string, or a URL that actually links to a resource?

Comment: hi i want http://www.google.com or wwww.google.com but not as www.google

Comment: The scheme-matching part seems incorrect - the way I read [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-17), a scheme must have at least 2 characters. RegExp seems to allow just one. A better RegExp might be: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\+\.-]+:`

Comment: I'm curious if you're just focused on google. because if not, then you will have a problem with sites like youtu.be, fb.me, goo.gl which are valid...

Comment: *www.google* is a validly **formated** URI (assuming a scheme like *HTTP* and *://* is prepended), the only way you can know it's not a real URI is to test it against a list of all valid URIs (a very long list) or send a request, presumbaly HTTP. That would most likely need to come from the server. So send the URI to the server and have it tested there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkURL(value) {
  var urlregex = new RegExp(
        "^((http|https|ftp)\://)*([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
  if(urlregex.test(value))
  {
    return(true);
  }
  return(false);
}
```

Comment: There are many schemes other than HTTP, HTTP and FTP (e.g. file). Host names don't have to start with *www* and URLs can include a port number (e.g. :80).

Comment: thank you but there is a problem when i type the www.google it also getting as valid url how could i avoid this

Comment: I have changed the regex. Now please check.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zqg7M/2/ , i again updated the answer and fiddle. CHeck them for www.google.com

Comment: @Coding-Freak: Your regular expression doesn't work on URLs with parentheses, like [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361664(loband).aspx).

Comment: But its not asked in the question whether it would validate pages also.

Comment: @Coding-Freak: URLs include paths, and the OP said URLs. They gave examples of URLs with paths to the root, but they never said they didn't want to validate the path.

Comment: This should be fun. It doesn't accept URLs with spaces in them.

Comment: whoohooo... i guess this question should be raised as a community wiki... because there can be so many possiblities of a url.

Comment: @roshan -  edit the question and check the mark as community wiki option

Comment: No need at all, there is a wikipedia page and the RFC is pretty clear (and many, many pages on the web already address the issue). The OP's requirement is poorly specified, it's still not clear what "valid" means.

Comment: @RobG - yes. I agree with you. Thanks.

Comment: @CodingFreak, both of your 'fiddles' allow for the invalid URL 'http:// goog' (ignore the space, I added that due to stockoverflow), which is not valid.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
  {
  echo "URL is not valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "URL is valid";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url:485 which is based on Steve Levithan's well-tested, standards-aware parseUri function.

Comment: Or something like: `ntfs://foo.bar@mysite.com:/what/the/home.dtb?thing=whatever&species=goose#beak`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2
$url = "http://www.example.com:80i/"; // Yes, I have an "i" after port 80, then is not a valid URL

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  echo "URL is valid";
} else {
  echo "URL is NOT valid";
}

$url = parse_url($url);

echo $url['port']; // Returns 80 (without the "i")

// BUG...
?>
```

Using filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL doesn't validate correctly the URL